# How do I use BindDynamic in my code? Type name not allowed

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, unreal-engine4

I am trying to follow a UE4 tutorial on how to use timelines in C++. However, when I try to use BindDynamic, the option to do so does not show up. An error "type name is not allowed" keeps showing up. Here Are the important parts of my code:

CPP

```
// Called when the game starts or when spawned  
void AMyCharacter::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    UpdateFunctionFloat.BindDynamic(this, &AMyCharacter, UpdateTimelineComp);

    if (ExampleTimelineCurve)
    {
        CrouchTimelineComp->AddInterpFloat(ExampleTimelineCurve, UpdateFunctionFloat);
    }

    TimelineFinishedFunction();
    CapsuleHalfHight = GetCapsuleComponent()->GetScaledCapsuleHalfHeight();
    standingCapsuleHalfHight = GetCapsuleComponent()->GetScaledCapsuleHalfHeight() * 2;
    cameraZOffset = FirstPersonCamera->GetRelativeLocation().Z;

    GunMesh->AttachToComponent(HandMesh,
        FAttachmentTransformRules::SnapToTargetNotIncludingScale,
        TEXT("GripPoint"));

}

void AMyCharacter::UpdateTimelineComp(float Output)
{
    float newCapsuleHight = Output;
    GetCapsuleComponent()->SetCapsuleHalfHeight(Output);
}


.h


protected:

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)

        class UTimelineComponent* CrouchTimelineComp;

    FOnTimelineEvent TimelineFinishedEvent;

    FOnTimelineFloat UpdateFunctionFloat;

    UFUNCTION()
        void UpdateTimelineComp(float Output);

    UFUNCTION()

        void TimelineFinishedFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
UpdateFunctionFloat.BindDynamic(this, &AMyCharacter, UpdateTimelineComp);
```

->

```
UpdateFunctionFloat.AddDynamic(this, &AMyCharacter::UpdateTimelineComp);
```